# IOS Step menu using swift

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to create the stepper menu in IOS using swift, But I'm facing some issues. Here are the issues.

1) Portrait and landscape stepper menu is not propper. 
2) How to set default step position with the method below method, It's working when button clicked. But I want to set when menu loads the first time.

```
self.stepView.setSelectedPosition(index: 2)
```

3) If it reached the position last, I would like to change the color for complete path parentPathRect.

4) Progress animation CABasicAnimation is not like the progress bar, I want to show the animation.

5) It should not remove the selected position color when changing the orientation.

As per my organization rules should not use third-party frameworks.

Can anyone help me with the solution? Or is there any alternative solution for this?

[image: Potrait]
[image: Landscape]

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, StepMenuDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var stepView: StepView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        self.stepView.delegate = self;

        self.stepView.titles = ["1", "2", "3"]
        self.stepView.lineWidth = 8
        self.stepView.offSet = 8
        self.stepView.setSelectedPosition(index: 2)
    }

    func didSelectItem(atIndex index: NSInteger) {
        print(index)
    }



}

protocol StepMenuDelegate {
    func didSelectItem(atIndex index: NSInteger)
}

class StepView: UIView {

    var delegate : StepMenuDelegate!

    var titles: [String] = [] {
        didSet(values) {
            setup()
            setupItems()
        }
    }

    var lineWidth: CGFloat = 8 {
        didSet(values) {
            setup()
        }
    }



    var offSet: CGFloat = 8 {
        didSet(values) {
            self.itemOffset = offSet * 4
            setup()
        }
    }

    private var selectedIndex : NSInteger!


    private var itemOffset : CGFloat = 8 {
        didSet (value) {

            setup()
            setupItems()

        }
    }

    private var path : UIBezierPath!

    var selectedLayer : CAShapeLayer!

    private var parentPathRect : CGRect!
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        self.setup()
        setupItems()
    }

    func setup() {
        self.removeAllButtonsAndLayes()

        let layer = CAShapeLayer()
        self.parentPathRect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: offSet, y: self.bounds.midY - (self.lineWidth/2) ), size: CGSize(width: self.bounds.width - (offSet * 2), height: lineWidth))
        path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.parentPathRect, cornerRadius: 2)
        layer.path = path.cgPath
        layer.fillColor = UIColor.orange.cgColor
        layer.lineCap = .butt
        layer.shadowColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
        layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 1, height: 2)
        layer.shadowOpacity = 0.1
        layer.shadowRadius = 2
        self.layer.addSublayer(layer)

    }

    func setupItems() {
        removeAllButtonsAndLayes()

        let itemRect = CGRect(x: self.itemOffset, y: 0, width: 34, height: 34)

        let totalWidth = self.bounds.width

        let itemWidth = totalWidth  / CGFloat(self.titles.count);

        for  i in 0..<self.titles.count {
            let button = UIButton()
            var xPos: CGFloat = itemOffset
            self.addSubview(button)

            xPos += (CGFloat(i) * itemWidth);
            xPos += itemOffset/3
            button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

            button.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor, constant: xPos).isActive = true
            button.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
            button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: itemRect.height).isActive = true
            button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: itemRect.width).isActive = true
            button.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
            button.layer.zPosition = 1
            button.layer.cornerRadius = itemRect.height/2
            let name : String = self.titles[i]
            button.tag = i
            button.setTitle(name, for: .normal)
            button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(selectedItemEvent(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)

            if self.selectedIndex != nil {
                if button.tag  == self.selectedIndex {
                    selectedItemEvent(sender: button)

                }
            }

        }

    }

    @objc func selectedItemEvent(sender:UIButton)  {
        if self.selectedLayer != nil {
            selectedLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()
        }
        self.delegate.didSelectItem(atIndex: sender.tag)
        let fromRect = self.parentPathRect.origin
        self.selectedLayer = CAShapeLayer()

        let rect = CGRect(origin: fromRect, size: CGSize(width:sender.frame.origin.x - 4, height: 8))
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, cornerRadius: 4)
        self.selectedLayer.path = path.cgPath
        self.selectedLayer.lineCap = .round
        self.selectedLayer.fillColor = UIColor.orange.cgColor

        let animation  = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "fillColor")
        animation.toValue = UIColor.blue.cgColor
        animation.duration = 0.2
        animation.fillMode = .forwards
        animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
        self.selectedLayer.add(animation, forKey: "fillColor")


        self.layer.addSublayer(self.selectedLayer)
    }

    func removeAllButtonsAndLayes() {
        for button in self.subviews {
            if button is UIButton {
                button.removeFromSuperview()
            }
        }
    }


    func setSelectedPosition(index:NSInteger) {
        self.selectedIndex = index
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I found One way to achieve the solution.!!

https://gist.github.com/DamodarGit/7f0f484708f60c996772ae28e5e1c615

Welcome to suggestions or code changes.!!